# how to open 2 excels continuously in c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I want to open 2 excel workbooks continuously(one after the one) in c#. How can I achieve this??
I used like below:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File1 + ".xls");
Response.TransmitFile(savepath);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File2 + ".xls");
Response.TransmitFile(savepath);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

However, Only one excel is transmitted, How can I get the second one also???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have not seen file download supporting multiple files at one click on web, unless zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is limited in this respect that each request can only handle a single response - you'd need to look at other ways of approaching this, such as issuing multiple requests via scripting from the client side, or combining your files into a single archive file (such as a ZIP file) prior to transmission

Comment: Hi, can you send me code base for zipping multiple excelsheets. I searched through google and nothing is working. Please send me codebase. Please its very urgent.Any help in this is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea - you can combine two excel files into one as separate sheets.